# python regex substitute group with variable

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

in python, need to substitute a group found in Regex string with a variable. but just substitute the group, not the entire regex result.

here is what I have so far:

```
content = "FILE_NAME(
           /* name */ 
           'test_name_to_replace.stp',
           /* time_stamp */ '2018-05-28T14:34:32+02:00',
           /* author */ (''),
           /* organization */ (''),"

replaceVariable = "New_Name.stp"
regex = r"(name.*\n*').*.stp"
subst = r"$1%s" % re.escape(replaceVariable)

New_Content = re.sub(regex, subst, content, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

the result I from the search "regex" is:

```
name */ 
'test_name_to_replace.stp
```

where group 1 is

```
name */ 
'
```

and group 0 is

```
test_name_to_replace.stp
```

I need to keep group 1 and replace group 0
but the subs string isn't working the special character $1 before the variable, I get a result like this:

```
New_Content = "FILE_NAME(
           $1New_Name.stp',
           /* time_stamp */ '2018-05-28T14:34:32+02:00',
           /* author */ (''),
           /* organization */ (''),"
```

it deletes the group1

Comment: Use `\1` to reference groups in python. Not `$1`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is always your friend, as this is very clearly documented in [Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> - `\number`
>
>   Matches the contents of the group of the same number.

But you don't need matching groups here, try using:

[`\'(\w+\.stp)\'`](https://regex101.com/r/7fGPVL/1)

And then:

```
subst = "'{}'".format(replaceVariable)
re.sub(r"\'(\w+\.stp)\'", subst, content, 0, re.MULTILINE)

# Result
FILE_NAME(
           /* name */ 
           'New_Name.stp',
           /* time_stamp */ '2018-05-28T14:34:32+02:00',
           /* author */ (''),
           /* organization */ (''),
```

Comment: what if the file name has digits and other characters?? the /w will not work

Comment: `\w` will match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`  So if you have other characters just use that explicit list and add as necessary

Comment: actually even better instead of \w I can use: [^']+.stp and I don't need to worry about the groups anymore. Its just mega slow!!!!!

Comment: That might allow invalid characters in a filename, but if that's not a concern, go for it.